# How to name first unnamed column header of a data frame in R

Tags: r

I have the following data frame

```
df <- structure(c("1450783_at Ifit1", "1417793_at Irgm2", "1418191_at Usp18",
"1445897_s_at Ifi35", "1438868_at Phf11d", "1438004_at Papd7",
"-0.946463848219996", "-1.02996255295994", "-1.08671744204772",
"-0.99957964419579", "-0.823103726651139", "-0.879596943746683",
"-0.81666670993138", "-0.751419221027377", "-0.771297530228225",
"-0.788962065407382", "-0.845247178175189", "-0.836283457880369",
"0.670196443309756", "0.654252942446252", "0.760493091259822",
"0.810593059985653", "0.701631078290633", "0.732997453122236",
"1.380387289393", "1.37328340394659", "1.27108996508917", "1.27736715351672",
"1.39124142575392", "1.35937709488124", "-0.287453174551374",
"-0.246154572405521", "-0.173568084073049", "-0.299418503899194",
"-0.424521599218227", "-0.376494146376421"), .Dim = c(6L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("1450783_at Ifit1", "1417793_at Irgm2", "1418191_at Usp18",
    "1445897_s_at Ifi35", "1438868_at Phf11d", "1438004_at Papd7"
    ), c("", "(3)ADX.ID.LN.x1", "(3)ADX.ID.LN.x2", "(3)ALM.ID.LN.x2",
    "(3)ALM.ID.LN.x1", "(3)ALM.ID.LN.x3")))
```

Which looks like this:

```
> df 
                                        (3)ADX.ID.LN.x1      (3)ADX.ID.LN.x2     
1450783_at Ifit1   "1450783_at Ifit1"   "-0.946463848219996" "-0.81666670993138" 
1417793_at Irgm2   "1417793_at Irgm2"   "-1.02996255295994"  "-0.751419221027377"
1418191_at Usp18   "1418191_at Usp18"   "-1.08671744204772"  "-0.771297530228225"
1445897_s_at Ifi35 "1445897_s_at Ifi35" "-0.99957964419579"  "-0.788962065407382"
1438868_at Phf11d  "1438868_at Phf11d"  "-0.823103726651139" "-0.845247178175189"
1438004_at Papd7   "1438004_at Papd7"   "-0.879596943746683" "-0.836283457880369"
                   (3)ALM.ID.LN.x2     (3)ALM.ID.LN.x1    (3)ALM.ID.LN.x3     
1450783_at Ifit1   "0.670196443309756" "1.380387289393"   "-0.287453174551374"
1417793_at Irgm2   "0.654252942446252" "1.37328340394659" "-0.246154572405521"
1418191_at Usp18   "0.760493091259822" "1.27108996508917" "-0.173568084073049"
1445897_s_at Ifi35 "0.810593059985653" "1.27736715351672" "-0.299418503899194"
1438868_at Phf11d  "0.701631078290633" "1.39124142575392" "-0.424521599218227"
1438004_at Papd7   "0.732997453122236" "1.35937709488124" "-0.376494146376421"
```

What I want to do is to name the first unamed columns with "ProbeGene".
So that it looks like this:

```
                       ProbeGene                 (3)ADX.ID.LN.x1      (3)ADX.ID.LN.x2     
1450783_at Ifit1   "1450783_at Ifit1"   "-0.946463848219996" "-0.81666670993138"
```

How can I achieve that?

I tried this `names(df)[1] <- "ProbeGene"` but failed.

Comment: Note that your data is currently stored as a matrix, not a data.frame. This is why the names() function didn't work and also why all of your numeric columns have to be stored as strings (matrices can only have one type).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change the `colnames` not the `names`

```
colnames(df)[1]<-"ProbeGene"
```

```
                     ProbeGene            (3)ADX.ID.LN.x1       (3)ADX.ID.LN.x2      (3)ALM.ID.LN.x2     (3)ALM.ID.LN.x1    (3)ALM.ID.LN.x3     
1450783_at Ifit1   "1450783_at Ifit1"   "-0.946463848219996" "-0.81666670993138"  "0.670196443309756" "1.380387289393"   "-0.287453174551374"
1417793_at Irgm2   "1417793_at Irgm2"   "-1.02996255295994"  "-0.751419221027377" "0.654252942446252" "1.37328340394659" "-0.246154572405521"
1418191_at Usp18   "1418191_at Usp18"   "-1.08671744204772"  "-0.771297530228225" "0.760493091259822" "1.27108996508917" "-0.173568084073049"
1445897_s_at Ifi35 "1445897_s_at Ifi35" "-0.99957964419579"  "-0.788962065407382" "0.810593059985653" "1.27736715351672" "-0.299418503899194"
1438868_at Phf11d  "1438868_at Phf11d"  "-0.823103726651139" "-0.845247178175189" "0.701631078290633" "1.39124142575392" "-0.424521599218227"
1438004_at Papd7   "1438004_at Papd7"   "-0.879596943746683" "-0.836283457880369" "0.732997453122236" "1.35937709488124" "-0.376494146376421"
```